# Rewrite mod для query string, используя всю строку

Tags: mod_rewrite, apache2, зеркало, rewrite

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как заставить апач отдать html файл, называемый целым `query_string` или его частью. То есть, допусти, запрос `http://site.ru/?p=1` отдал без редиректа html файл в корне `?p=1` или хотя бы `p=1`.

Возникли проблемы с созданием как можно более идентичных html зеркал своих сайтов через puf (может, инструменты посоветуете для этого, многопоточные) - минусы puf как раз с get параметрами и css картинками.

Спасибо!

Comment: @Roundik Сложно понять, что Вы хотите. Возможно, так:

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} p=(\d+)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/%1.html? [L]

Ваш URL: http://site.ru/?p=1

На выходе: http://site.ru/1.html

[Проверяйте здесь](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!
Дело в том, что страницы сайта закачиваются с помощью подобия телепорта и сохраняются просто как %{QUERY_STRING}.

То есть если скачивается страница сайта с запросом query string: http://site.ru/?p=1&s=1, то puf(программа на подобии телепорта под линукс) сохраняет эту страницу как ?p=1&s=1 - без расширения. Нам нужно добиться чтобы она открывалась по тому же адресу http://site.ru/?p=1&s=1
Грубо говоря, http://site.ru/%{QUERY_STRING} открывал страницу в корне ?p=1&s=1.
То есть цель стоит перед нами - сохранить всю структуру сайта в том же виде.